# Why Do I See Two Results?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I'm working through Sasa Juric's "Elixir In Action" and I spotted something I find a little bit puzzling.  I was working through the examples he gives around page 140 or so and I saw this:

```
iex(2)> send(self, {:message, 1})    # Line 1
{:message, 1}
iex(3)> receive_result = receive do
...(3)>   {:message, x} -> x + 2
...(3)> end
3
iex(4)> IO.inspect receive_result
3
3
```

Why does `IO.inspect` print the value twice? Is it related to the send message on Line 1 immediately displaying the tuple?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how [IO.inspect/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2) works in iex:

```
iex(10)> IO.inspect(3)
3 # From IO.inspect
3 # return value in iex
```

This happens since IO.inspect prints the value and returns the same value. [IO.puts/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/IO.html#puts/2) prints the value and returns `:ok`

```
iex(11)> IO.puts(3)  
3    # From IO.puts
:ok  # return value in iex
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answer, there's a noteworthy scenario where `IO.puts` won't be appropriate: when inspecting large objects.

If you're working with a large object that gets truncated with `...`, and you want to see the entire object using `limit: :infinity`, you can avoid the double print by appending `nil` on the same line:

```
IO.inspect(big_object, limit: :infinity); nil
```

This method provides a single print of your object. It's important to note that `IO.puts` cannot accept the `limit: :infinity` option, so it wouldn't be suitable for this case.